# VS and SQL Server compact. Always takes the absolute path instead of the relative one when deploying

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-ce

I have a VS solution (C#) which uses the Entity Framework with an SQL Server compact database in the background.

Everything works fine on my machine.

My app.config uses the connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="dataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/data.csdl|res://*/data.ssdl|res://*/data.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string='Data Source=|DataDirectory|\files\data.sdf;Max Database Size=" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Source=|DataDirectory|\files\data.sdf works and is the thing used by VS, because when I change it, let's say to "\files\data.foobar", it won't start up and give me an error.

So, everything works when I run it on my computer, but when I publish it or even copy the whole folder to another computer it won't run.

I'll get the error that *D:\(My local project directory)\files\data.sdf* can't be found. Of course not, it should use *|DataDirectory|\files\data.sdf* and not the absolute path.

Where does it still reference the absolute original path? I can't find anything. I cleaned the solution. I even deleted the whole thing and re-downloaded it from SC. Somehow, when publishing it, it's still using somewhere the absolute path to the database file in the connection string.

I even ran a full text search over my solution folder for *My local directory* name and couldn't find anything.

This is driving me crazy. Some ideas would be appreciated.

---

Edit:

The full [app.config](http://pastebin.com/tG67AQuV).

The error I get when I try to run it on another computer:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database. [ Path = D:\Users\MyUser\Dokumente\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\moderator\moderator\files\data.sdf ]
```

So, somewhere it still uses the absolute path to the db file, and I can't find out where it is this getting from

---

Edit 2:

Was able to work around this by playing with the entity framework build action settings (and moving the database file to the main directory). Still doesn't work when I publish it, but works when I copy the whole project.

Also, I now have two database files, the on in the main directory I use when debugging and on in the /bin/release folder.

There's surely something wrong with the file path handling but at least it works now.

Comment: Do you have an `App_Data` folder in the project directory?

Comment: I don't, it's a forms application. "|DataDirectory|" seems to work there as well tough, but I also tried to use just something like "\files\data.sdf" instead of "|DataDirectory|\files\data.sdf" and got still the same results. 

I even moved data.sdf to the main application folder and removed the path in the config file, so I used Data Source=data.sdf but it stlll tried to access the local absolute path on other systems.

Comment: Ah, so do you have a `files` folder in your project directory then?

Comment: In your resource file? And show ius some code, please

Comment: Yes, I have a "files" directory which contains the databe file data.sfd. 

My whole App.config looks like [that](http://pastebin.com/tG67AQuV).


Works well locally, but when trying to run on another system it somehow uses the original absolute path (pointing to my original local folder).

Comment: Error I get on other systems:

    **System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database. [ Path = D:\Users\MyUser\Dokumente\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\moderator\moderator\files\data.sdf ]**

So somewhere it's still using the absolute local path, but it's correct in the [App.config](http://pastebin.com/tG67AQuV).